# How to Insert bitmap image to sqlite database on Windows phone 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have managed to pick an image from the phones library and display it. this is the code. Question is how do i Insert this image into my Sqlite database of contacts and retrieve it and display it again after getting the image? Here is my code. A detailed step by step instruction would be appreciated from here.

```
     namespace Mobile_Life.Pages
{

public sealed partial class NextOFKin_Update_Delete : Page
    {
        int Selected_ContactId = 0;
        DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
        Contacts currentcontact = new Contacts();
        CoreApplicationView view;

        public NextOFKin_Update_Delete()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
            view = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();

        }

        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                Frame.GoBack();
            }
        }

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ShowAsync();
            Selected_ContactId = int.Parse(e.Parameter.ToString());
            currentcontact = Db_Helper.ReadContact(Selected_ContactId);//Read selected DB contact
            namestxt.Text = currentcontact.Name;//get contact Name
            relationtxt.Text = currentcontact.Relation;//get contact relation
            phonetxt.Text = currentcontact.PhoneNumber;//get contact PhoneNumber

        }

        private void Update_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentcontact.Name = namestxt.Text;
            currentcontact.Relation = relationtxt.Text;
            currentcontact.PhoneNumber = phonetxt.Text; 
            Db_Helper.UpdateContact(currentcontact);//Update selected DB contact Id
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(NextOfKin));
        }

        private void Delete_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Db_Helper.DeleteContact(Selected_ContactId);//Delete selected DB contact Id.
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(NextOfKin));
        }

        private void profile_img(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

            // Filter to include a sample subset of file types
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

            filePicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
            view.Activated += viewActivated;
        }

        private async void viewActivated(CoreApplicationView sender, IActivatedEventArgs args1)
        {
            FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;

            if (args != null)
            {
                if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;

                view.Activated -= viewActivated;
                StorageFile storageFile = args.Files[0];
                var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
                profile.ImageSource = bitmapImage;


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not just save the path to the image that is in the phones library into the sqlite database rather than trying to same the image itself?

Comment: will give that a try. Though in case the user deletes the image from phone wouldn't it be affected?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be NOT to store the image in SQLite. Just copy it to your `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` and save the path.

If you really want to store the BitmapImage in SQLite, just convert it to byte array: [Convert a bitmapimage to byte[] array for storage in sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633439/convert-a-bitmapimage-to-byte-array-for-storage-in-sqlite-database)